# Is there a way to have pseudo property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Let say if there is already class properties of

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) JJNode *leftChild;
@property (strong, nonatomic) JJNode *rightChild;
```

and the app already makes extensive use of `if (parent.leftChild) { ... }` and `parent.leftChild = newNode` (both getter and setter).

But say, the class might work better if the left and right child can be represented by an `NSMutableArray` object, so that the class can support N-children in the future, and looping through the children is easier.

So it will be

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *childrenArray;
```

and in some cases, the children can be iterated by

```
for (JJNode *node in self.childrenArray) { ... }
```

But using this new array, can we still be able to keep on using `parent.leftChild` and `parent.leftChild = newNode`?

I wonder if it is a good practice, as it may seem like `parent.leftChild` and `(JJNode *)[parent objectAtIndex: 0]` are different objects, but in fact the same thing.  But say if we go ahead and do it, can we have pseudo property to achieve that?

It seems that we can actually use `@property (strong, nonatomic) JJNode *leftChild;` and change the getter and setter to actually use the array, but there will be two extra instance variables.  Can it be done without the ivars?  Or can we define 2 methods so that `parent.leftChild = newNode` will actually invoke some setter method, and `parent.leftChild` will invoke a getter?

Comment: This is a VERY bad idea. Index out of bounds exceptions anyone?

Comment: But yes, you can have a property with a custom implementation, just define the `-setLeftChild:` method in your implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your properties are not limited to synthesized ones - in fact, they are no more than a pair of methods that follow a certain naming convention.

You can remove the `@synthesize` instructions for the `leftChild` and `rightChild`, and replace them with methods that get/set the first and the second elements of the `NSArray` that holds nodes in case when there are more than two.

Comment: must be have two extra instance variables that actually are not used?

Comment: @JeremyL You can drop the instance variables altogether, and use the `NSArray` to hold the two sides.

Comment: @JeremyL: A property is not an instance variable. It's an abstraction of a getter (and possibly setter) method. Usually the thing that it gets or sets is an instance variable, but just like with any other getter or setter, that's not required. If you don't `@synthesize` the variables, there won't be any.

Comment: To clarify, the line `@property JJNode variable` doesn't actually create an instance variable, all it says is 'this class will have a method called variable that returns a JJNode, and another method called 'setVariable'. The `@synthesize` is what creates the instance variable. You can change it to `@dynamic` (to prevent compiler warnings) - this tells the system 'don't create an instance variable, I'll create the methods manually and handle what they do myself'. Then you can just access your custom NSArray in - leftChild, - rightChild, - setLeftChild, and - setRightChild however you wish.

Comment: it seems like the most recent behavior is, if no `@synthesize` is used, then there is `_leftChild` created for you, but if a `@dynamic leftChild;` is used, then no instance variable is created and the method `-leftChild` and `-setLeftChild` can both be defined and used just like a property, such as `parent.leftChild = node`

Comment: if `leftChild` is a `strong` property, does `setLeftChild` need to do a `[leftChild retain];`?  Because that's not allowed in ARC

Comment: @JeremyL If you are not synthesizing properties, the modifiers such as `nonatomic`, `strong`, and so on, are ignored. `NSMutableArray` will retain the object for you, providing an equivalent of a `strong` property.

Comment: In ARC, you need never call retain (or release/autorelease) - appropriate calls will be made at the necessary times. So if you're using ARC, no.